# What is the way to map preexisting tables in MSSQL with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to connect MSSQL database and then I want to map an preexisting table and make entries to it using the ORM.
There are couple of reason why I want to use the mapping method instead of creating my own class but the main one is that I need to store XML files and SQLAlchemy is not suited for the XML type that MSSQL provides.

Here is description of what I tried and why it does not work:

I am establishing a connection with the data base and them mapping the table this way:

```
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
Base= declarative_base()

class MyClass(Base):
    __table__ = Table('my_table_name', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

This throws an exception when executed:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class MyClass->my_table_name could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'my_table_name'
```

While inspecting the table in the Microsoft SSMS application there is not "PRIMARY KEY" in any of the columns which is strange. I checked each of the columns and found that column "Id" is IDENTITY column and I guess that this is used as PK.

I read some articles in google and in stackoverflow and found that I can use the mapper arguments to set a **primary_key** this way:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __table__ = Table('my_table_name', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key':[Table('my_table_name', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine).c.Id,]
    }
```

This is working fine and there are no exception when executing code. I tried to make an entry to the table using the new mapped class:

```
new_entry = MyClass(
Id = 9999,
... all other not null objects
)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(new_entry)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

I get the following exception:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'my_table_name' when 
IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I removed the "Id" Column fro the new_entry but still  get the same error no matter what  columns I fill or remove. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looking at the error you are not using MySQL, but MS SQL Server.